# ImportError: DLL load failed: The operating system cannot run %1. Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)

Tags: python, scrapy, anaconda

My Operating System is Win10-x64.

I run scrapy command: `scrapy startproject tutorial` in MS-DOS window then get the following error message:

[image: Image 1]

I am sure i have installed scrapy, but any scrapy command is not working.

I notice the log: "**from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib**" and i seach the file ***cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl*** found it ***_openssl*** is a ***.pyd*** file.

[image: Image 2]

it seems there is some error exist in this file.

I also notice that the OpenSSL package in Anaconda was built with vc9, I install the micro runtime environment and it didn't help me.

Comment: remove unnecessary * in ``

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `conda-forge` channel which contains up to date packages.

```
conda install scrapy -c conda-forge
```

Note: Use a new environment as it's likely you installed `cryptography` (and possibly `lxml`) via `pip`, and that may not play well with a `conda` environments.

Comment: Thank you. This command updated 3 packages in my machine:   conda-env-2.6.0, conda-4.2.13, scrapy-1.2.2. 
but my issue is still exist. i can't remember how did i install scrapy...

Comment: Try to create a new env: @conda create -n scrapyenv scrapy -c conda-forge@. If the issue persist I would reinstall anaconda as it's likely the compiled libraries were overwritten somehow by pip.

Comment: Thank you. I have find a solution. I post it at the following

Answer (score 1):

**name** = scrapy or cryptography

Just `pip uninstall "name"` as its likely for conda to tell you some of the uninstall cannot be done due to dependencies.

Thereafter `pip install "name"`

Problem is likely to be solved by now.

Answer (score 0):

I Build OpenSSL WIN64 release version with Visual studio 2015, and replace libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll to "C:\Windows\System32", then scrapy command work. it also said that built a WIN32 version is better, but i didn't try.
I built dynamic libraries, not static libraries.
Build Command for anyone interest:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin
vcvars64.bat
perl Configure VC-WIN64A no-asm --prefix="c:\openssl-1.0.2j\build-vc14-debug-win64-dll"
ms\do_win64a.bat
nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak
nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak test
nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak install
nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak clean
```